Reversing a Specific Range of Numbers
I have a range of numbers that goes from 0.25(min) to 0.50(max) and at the same time a range of numbers from 0(min) to 1(max). How can I make it so that as the first set of numbers increase the second set of numbers decrease so that 0.25=1 all the way to 0.50=0.
is there a specific equation to complete this seamlessly?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Is $y=2-4x$ what you're looking for?

The first set of numbers has a range of $0.25$ and the second has a range of $1$, with $0.25$ mapping to $1$ and $0.50$ mapping to $0$.
This means the equation should be of the form $y=-4x+c$ for some $c$.
We can now sub this into the mapping of $0.25$ to $1$ to get that $1=-4(0.25)+c$, so $c=2$.
This gives us $y=-4x+2$.

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but it sounds like you're looking for the function
$$f(x) = \frac{1-0}{0.25-0.50} (x - 0.50) + 0 = -4 x + 2$$
(see: the two-point formula for a line).
